# How to make a progress bar with links?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

So I'm creating an application form, and i have 9 pages of questions. at first, i had a progress bar that filled up by 1/9 every time one of the pages were completed.
but i was told i can't do that, and must have a sort of "box" system where i have 9 boxes in a line with a title in each box, so that is the person wants to go back 3 pages to change something, they can just click on it.

At the moment, I have a Navigation bar at the top, which is just and unordered list, set to display inline and for the bullets to be invisible, and that works quite well, so I tried to just use that, but change the words, and use it as my navigation but it's not the right size, and i need to make it so when the page has bee filled out, that section will turn purple to signify it's done, while the others remain gray.

Comment: Do people have to complete one page before being able to see a link to the next page? Is this being handled with PHP?

Comment: Yes they have to complete the page first, but i want them to then be able to go back at will. and yes, it's being handled by php, but i don't handle the php part, so if that's essential to fixing it, i'm pretty much screwed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't really need a progress bar, right?

What you can do is simply add a class to the selected item and then style everything after that accordingly:

```
li {
    background:#aff; /* This is the "already done" colour. */
}

li.selected ~ li {
    background:#f5f5f5; /* This is the "not yet reached" colour. */
}

li.selected {
    background:#5a0; /* This is the "selected" colour. */
}
```

To begin with, your very first `li` would be given the `current` class.

Here's an example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KkQb3/1/

If you then want to go back to another one you can use a new class:

```
li {
    background:#aff; /* This is the "already done" colour. */
}

li.selected ~ li {
    background:#f5f5f5; /* This is the "not yet reached" colour. */
}

li.selected {
    /* This is the no longer the "selected" colour. */
}

li.current {
    background:#5ae; /* This is the new "selected" colour. */
}
```

New JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KkQb3/2/ (You'd probably want to name "selected" to something different in this case.)

Comment: ooooooooooh, i don't know why i didn't think of doing that...
:-S
Thank you!